# Net has only one pin in Altuim

Tags: altium

I am getting a schematic compile error "Net  has only one pin." How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: What's the error starting with Net NetIC1_9 (No. 73)?

Comment: I'm not sure who gave the OP a -1 on this. It's a valid question, and this is not the first time it's happened. Altium can be pretty picky in that way. This is a great learning opportunity. +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of your net labels are off-grid and do not appear to be connected to the wires:

[image]

It is really important to use the snap grid. Otherwise things get very sloppy, like in your schematic.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty idiotic feature of this tool. Why would off-grid elements have no connection if they have explicit net names? (Rhetorical question)

Comment: @Ale the problem is if it's a small amount amount out it won't think the nets AHO1 and R19 are connected. One handy way to find out if they are is to drag one and see if they stay connected, and if they do hit ctrl-z to undo the movement otherwise reposition them until they're connected.

Comment: A previous answer regarding Altium's brain-dead use of grids in Schematic: [https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409271/grid-mismatch-in-altium/409346#409346](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409271/grid-mismatch-in-altium/409346#409346)