# Straighten schematic connections in Altium

Tags: altium

I noticed that the wires in Altium are not straight. Is there a way to ensure that they stay straight?

[image]

Comment: there should be a `snap to` setting

Comment: yes, thank you. However, I can only apply to all my new conections. I wonder if there is a way to apply it to previous connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a grid spacing of 2.54 mm (100 mil) in Altium schematic editor.

In the bottom left corner of Altium, you can see the current grid size:

[image: Altium grid size display]

In the properties inspector, you can change it by setting **Visible Grid**, **Snap Grid**, and **Snap Distance**. I find that the following settings work well for my usage:

[image: Altium properties inspector]

Of course, this comes down to your preference, but there are [some](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/409271/2028) reasons to use this value.

Once you've changed the grid, you can align objects to the new grid setting by selecting them and then selecting **Align** > **Align to Grid** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).

[image: Altium Align to Grid option]

More information from Altium here: [Defining Schematic Grid Preferences](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/sch-dlg-schprefsform-gridsandunitsschematic-grids-ad)

Comment: Thank you! Just worked it out :)

Answer (score 1):

To align connections you first to have to change your grid size to be larger to avoid granular changes in the line e.g. 50 mil is good. Then select the wire. click align, then align to grid.