# Altium Designer errors updating PCB project

Tags: altium

I am a Student of Electronic Engineering from Seville´s University.

This summer I am trying to make an egg incubator using an Arduino but I am doing the footprint for making the PCB on Altium.

The problem that I have is that when I go to "Design" and I update the PCB, I get a lot of errors (shown in the images).

I have revised all pins and still I have the "pin error" and with the other error of "Failed to add class member: component...". I have checked the library and the pins and it is OK.

I don´t know if I have made the sketch wrong, but I would like if someone would help me because I have one month like this.

I would like it if someone can help or give me the solution or I don´t know but I am tired of read a lot of articles and still the same...

Hi guys!

I have read all your comments and thanks for all.

But my problem is in my "arduino piece" because when I go to "Design" and "Update PCB in Schematic" I go to validates changes. then I have the "failed to add a class member" but i go to "execute changes" and everything is fixed   . So when I look at the Schematic Its seem that everythig is conected but minus arduino and still I´ve got "pin failure" (I´ve checked arduino a few times).

I have update the photos.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Normally I'd spend some time editing your question and helping to answer, but here I'm going to write why I down-voted. First, this isn't a forum, so you do NOT ask for private messaging links or email addresses. Second, if you can't be bothered to capitalize and spell correctly, it just sends the message that you aren't that serious about it. Which is why I'm commenting instead of going to extra effort for free.

Comment: Ok my fault its my first time to be here. I would like to say Sorry and it wont append again but I dont know what to do or where i can go... because i have asked my teachers and they dont help me to... :c

Comment: You can edit your question. Just click edit, and spend a moment to clean it up. There are lots of Altium users here and many of us are happy to help when it seems worthwhile.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited your question, provided an answer, and removed the downvote. Please take a moment to review what I've edited and then check out the site's [help page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Secret trick....   The errors don't need stop you.  If you look at your copper and you "know" it's connected right, you don't need to worry about the errors.

Comment: Maybe you don’t have time for it.. but look into Robert Feranec’s Altium course (just basic course to make a switched power supply)

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the termos part in the schematic library?

Comment: The errors saying "Unknown Pin" mean that the pin numbers in your schematic symbol do not match the pin numbers in your footprint symbol. They must match in order for the tool to know which schematic pin goes with which PCB footprint pin

Comment: I can't see the rest of the "Failed to add class member" errors, so I can't  help you much there

Comment: Hi, the footprints are associated with the components but I am looking the youtube chanels and still doesn´t work I will update more photos if you can suggest me guys how to fix it.

Comment: Pins on schematic symbols have Names, usually shown inside the component box, and Numbers, shown outside the box, above the pin.  The schematic pin Numbers must match the PCB footprint pin numbers. The PCB program doesn't care about the pin Names.

Answer (score 2):

Before trying to create or update a PCB, you should **Validate** your schematic. (Project > Validate PCB Project). This is also shown when you try to update the PCB. Errors can prevent the update process from working correctly.

The **Messages** panel (View > Panels > Messages) will list any errors and warnings that the schematic has based on the [Error Reporting configuration](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/accessing-defining-managing-project-options#error_reporting) under project options (Project > Project Options > Error Reporting tab).

The visible errors in your image are:

- Unknown pin
- Failed to add class member (under add component class)

##### Unknown pin

The unknown pins correspond to components which you've assigned the designators `TERMOS` and `RELOJ1`.

*(Note that designators in schematics are commonly assigned using just one or two characters followed by a number. For integrated circuits or "chips" these are usually `U`. Instead of `TERMOS`, that component might be better designated `U1`. Connectors and jacks might be assigned `CN` or `J`, so instead of `RELOJ1` it would just be `J1`.)*

Do your symbols — the components in a schematic — have valid footprints associated with them? It appears that you have a symbol to which you've connected wires, but when you try to publish to the PCB, it can't find the appropriate pads that would be associated with its footprint. You should read up on [how to create footprints](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/creating-pcb-footprint).

When you say *"I have checked the library and the pins and it is ok."* what do you mean? Did your [library compile without any errors](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-integrated-libraries)? Have you verified the symbol pins all correspond to footprint pins? Refer to the link above (re: how to create footprints) if not.

##### Failed to add class member

The failure to add class members is a secondary effect of not having working footprints. When Altium adds a component footprint to a PCB, it (by default) also adds that PCB component to a component or room class based on the schematic sheet it is on. If the footprint were working, this error would likely disappear. Nevertheless, you may want to review [how class generation works](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/accessing-defining-managing-project-options#class_generation).

##### Other possible validation errors

Based on your images, I'll list some other potential issues:

Are you using a standard grid for your schematic editing? You have little kinks and bends in your wires which suggests you're having some problems here. Symbol pins and wires on the schematic can be difficult to connect properly if the symbol uses one grid pitch and the schematic editor uses another. It is highly recommended (but not required) to use 2.54 mm (100 mil) grid spacing for both. It's possible to have wires that *look* connected but actually aren't, which can result in errors during schematic validation.

Previous questions/answers related to this:

- [Straighten schematic connections in Altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/599264/2028)
- [Grid Mismatch in Altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/409271/2028)

The Arduino in the center of your schematic still has a wildcard placeholder for its designator (`*`). As above, you should assign it a designator that you can use to refer to it, as well as avoid schematic annotation errors. You can maintain all the designators manually, or use the [annotation tools](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/annotating-design-components).

Finally, there are lots of good resources on the web, but you may have missed them. In particular, you should know about and use:

- [Altium Designer Official Documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer)
- [Altium Designer User Forum](https://forum.live.altium.com/)
- [Altium Academy Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/AltiumAcademy)

There are also great users who've posted countless hours of content that often teach a great deal about PCB design and Altium in particular.

- [Robert Ferenac's Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/RobertFeranec)

---

As you can see, there's a great deal of information that goes into answering your question. If you have further questions, you should use one of the resources above, or ask a ***new*** question. (Don't add a comment below to ask a new question.) Hopefully the information I've provided will help you narrow the problem down, and if you continue to have errors, you can post a new question that is *specific* to an error. Being specific is how to get definitive, useful answers.